# Each quadrilateral contains a point that splits it into four areas of equal size

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to prove the following; for every quadrilateral, there exists a point such that if we draw a straight line from this point to all the corners of the quadrilateral, all the areas of the triangles formed by this have the same area.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that the area of the quadrilateral is 1, thus this point would split the area into four triangles all of which have the area of $1/4$. My intuition is telling me that one should consider the case of convex and nonconvex quadrilaterals separately.

Comment: I think your problem is overdetermined, because you have only $2$ degrees of freedom, which are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, and $3$ constraints, which are the areas of $3$ of the triangles.  Therefore, I think in most cases there will be no solution.

Comment: Let consider convex quadrilateral ABCD. Let E is middle of diagonal BD, F is point such that areas of triangles ABF, BCF, CDF, ADF are equal. In order to satisfy area ABF = area ADF point F must lie on the line AE. In order to satisfy area BCF = area CDF point F must lie on the line CE. Then F must coincide E or line AE must coincide line CE. In first case we need area ABD = area BCD. In second case we need area ABC = area ACD. Then in order for such point F to exist one of diagonals must divide quadrilateral into two equal area parts. Then middle of this diagonal will be point F.

Answer (score 1):

Assume w.l.o.g. that you have area one, as you already suggested. Also assume a convex quad for now, for easier thinking. If you have one edge if a triangle, and its area, then the opposite vertex is constrained to lie on a line parallel to the edge.

If you take two adjacent edges of the quad, say $AB$ and $BC$, you get two lines on which the central point has to lie. So in general (barring any degenerate situations) you get two lines intersecting, and that's your central point $P$.

However, you can now play the same game again with the edges of the triangles you just formed. Take $AP$ and $CP$ and you again get two lines and $D$ has to lie on the intersection of these two lines. Can you prove that it always does? Since you can move $D$ in such a way that the area of the quad doesn't change (one real degree of freedom there), most original positions of $D$ will not match the constraints we have for it. So in general you'll get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. It is true when we have at least 2 Sides Parallel.

Let $ABCD$ be the Quadrilateral.

**CASE 1 : $AB$ not Parallel to $CD$**

Consider Side $AB$ making a triangle with the Center Point $P$. The triangle $PAB$ has some base $AB$ & hence the height $H$ will be such that $H \times AB / 2 = 1 / 4$ , which means $P$ will be on the line Parallel ($P1$) to the base & at this Distance. The other side $CD$ (not Parallel) will also have such a Parallel line ($P2$).
Where these two Parallel lines ($P1$ & $P2$) intersect, we have to get the Point $P$.

[image: NO SOLUTION]

**CASE 1A** : In case , this Point $P$ gives Equal Area triangles with all Sides , we are Done. In general, this is unlikely.

**CASE 1B** : In Case , we do not get Equal Area triangles with all Sides with Point $P$ , then there is no Solution. [[ This is what User "Erin is high class" is Pointing to ]] In general , this is likely.

**CASE 2 : $AB$ Parallel to $CD$**

Now consider $AB$ is Parallel to $CD$ , then the two Parallel lines ($P1$ & $P2$) will be Exact Same & hence $P$ is still not Determined. Then we can use $BC$ to make a new line ($P3$) Parallel to the base of the triangle $PBC$ & hence Determine $P$ where $P1$ , $P2$ & $P3$ Intersect.

[image: SOLUTION]

This Point $P$ will make Equal Area with $CD$ too.
We get this Solution in this case.

**Alternative way to look at this :**

When we have the Parallel line $P1$ coinciding with $P2$ between the Parallel lines $AB$ & $CD$ , we can take a Point $P$ in this line at the intersection with $BC$ & move that Point $P$ continuously to the intersection with $DA$. We can see that the triangle $PBC$ will vary between $0$ (minimum) & $1/2$ (maximum) , whereas the triangle $PDA$ will vary between $1/2$ (maximum) & $0$ (minimum) which means that there is a Point where Area of each will be $1/4$ (Equal).
We already have the other 2 triangles with Area 1/4. Hence we have the Solution.

**CASE 2 always has Solution.**
Quadrilateral with 2 Sides Parallel is a trapezium.
Quadrilateral with 2 Sides Parallel & other 2 Sides Parallel is a Parallelogram.

**CASE 1 may or may not have Solution.**